# PHP PDO with MSSQL always returns no results if the query contains a JOIN

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

As soon as I add any join to a query made with PHP PDO for MSSQL (dblib) on WAMP, result set is empty. If I remove the join, results come back.

I tested the query with join in SSMS and it returns values, so the query it is correct.

Empty result set (but there are results if run in SSMS):

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT GPS.Lat AS Lng, GPS.Long AS Lat FROM SIBA_Beni B LEFT JOIN SIBA_Città C ON B.Città = C.ID;");
$sth->execute();
$beni = $sth->fetchAll();
var_dump($beni);die;
```

Working:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT GPS.Lat AS Lng, GPS.Long AS Lat FROM SIBA_Beni B;");
$sth->execute();
$beni = $sth->fetchAll();
var_dump($beni);die;
```

Comment: Have you tried executing the query with the join in management studio?

Comment: yes.I wrote it above

Comment: Yes sorry, I must have overlooked that. I noticed the query contains Unicode characters in it. It could be a codepage issue.

Comment: No because I tried to join with another table without accents in the name and I face the same issue

Comment: It could be a multitude of things to be honest. But another thing to check is the database you're connecting to. You're referencing tables without schema/db names ie database.dbo.objectname. Is `SIBA_Città` in the same database as the other table?

Comment: @JohnBell yes. I have only one database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the charset. Not in table names, but in returned rows.